# Не могу подключить класс, имя которого передаётся через параметр (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Выдаёт ошибку: Class 'story' not found.

Пробовал первую букву большую - не помогло.

маршрут:

```
Route::get('/new/sorttopforever/{item?}/{sort?}', 'IndexController@sortTopForever')
->name('sorttopforever');
```

модель:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Story extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'story';
}
```

контроллер:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use App\Bezdna;
use App\Story;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function sortTopForever($item, $sort)
    {
        //вот так не работает $elems = $item::all();
        if ($item == 'story')
            $elems = Story::all();

        if ($item == 'bezdna')
            $elems = Bezdna::all();

        $elems = $elems->sortByDesc($sort);
        $elems = $elems->values()->all();

        return view('story.show', [
            'elems' => $elems,
            'key' => Auth::check() ? true : false,
            'item' => 'story'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего не приходят аргументы в метод, или приходят не те значения, что Вы ждёте. Попробуйте воспользоваться dd() или dump(), чтобы проверить значения переменных $item и $sort:

```
...    
public function sortTopForever(string $item, string $sort)
{
    dd("\$item = '$item'; \$sort = '$sort';")        
    if ($item === 'story') {
        $elems = Story::all();
    } elseif ($item === 'bezdna') {
        $elems = Bezdna::all();
    } else {
        ...
    }
    
    ...
```

PS: Не претендую на ответ - здесь просто можно писать код, в отличие от комментариев.

PPS: Извиняюсь за занудство, но настоятельно рекомендую оборачивать блоки кода в фигурные кавычки и придерживаться [соглашения сообщества о наименовании](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8) - код будет значительно проще и читабельнее.

Answer (score 0):

> вот так не работает $elems = $item::all();

У тебя класс находится в App. Добавь перед

> $elems = $item::all();

что-то в духе

```
$item = 'App\' . ucfirst($item)
```

PS. Вангую что проблема гораздо бОльше, и кроется в bad design, а сабж так, следствие и симптоматика. На будущее, посвяти пару-тройку предложений в вопросе тому, что хочешь сделать. *А* - тебе могут предложить альтернативный способ решения проблемы, *Б* - людям будет легче понять истоки проблемы.

PPS. Мой ответ решает конкретно твой затык с вызовом класса. Использовать такую конструкцию как у тебя - плохо.